# Android Firebase realtime database replacing data instead of adding new data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to insert data into Firebase realtime database. The logic of my app is to create a new field containing username and password under users column in the database when the user is signing up.

The app requires an email, username, and password when signing up. I am using Firebase Auth to do this. When I run the app, I can sign up and insert the values in the database successfully, but the values are being replaced in the database whenever a new user signs up instead of creating a new user.
Please help, if I am doing something wrong. This is my code.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(username,password);
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            databaseReference.child("users").setValue(userInformation);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Be *very* careful storing plain-text password in your database. It is a very bad practice and a great way to quickly lose user trust.

Answer (score 6):

```
databaseReference.child("users").setValue(userInformation)
```

This will replace the existing data. If you want to add the value as a new child, you will need to use `push()` , this will generate a unique id and then insert the new data. Try the code below.

```
databaseReference.child("users").push().setValue(userInformation)
```

Comment: When we're talking about users, I'd recommend storing them under their UID instead of a push ID: `databaseReference.child("users").child(task.getUser().getUid()).setValue(userInformation)`. This makes it easy to look up the user's information later and ensure you store each user only once (since logging in the same user next time will give them the same UID).

Answer (score 0):

Use this query. It will definitely start working for you.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(user);
```